# Is it possible to force DNS settings to update on a Windows 7 client with DHCP from the server?

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008, dhcp

Is there a command line or gui tool that I can use to make a client update its local nic settings without making them reboot or ipconfig /renew?  I changed the DNS settings but the computers that have already received their IP address via dhcp need the new dns settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the DNS settings and keep the clients as "auto obtain DNS settings from DHCP", then the answer is NO. However, you can set the DNS setting remotely using the **netsh** command line. Please note when you set the DNS using that command, you statically change the client's network properties.